# programatically generate x,y coordinate to position items on grid layout with 3 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure how to ask this. I have to generate a json object where I'm returning x and y position for each items of a list to position them on a grid. This is a 3 columns grid with 3 elements for each row of the grid.

so I need a dict like this for each item (which I will be able to append):

```
widget = {
"name": "item_name",
"xPos": "x",
"yPos": "y"
}
```

I'm looping through an object:

```
for count, item in enumerate(response, 1):
    print(count)
    print(item.name)
    //generate coordinate here
```

and I think that I some point I will need to generate a matrix like this:

```
Item_count,x,y  
1 0,0
2 1,0
3 2,0
4 0,1
5 1,1
6 2,1
7 0,2
8 1,2
9 2,2 
etc...
```

How can I do this? I don't really even know where to start.

Comment: Where are the values coming from? Can you give example input?

Comment: thanks for asking. I've updated my question. but I don't think it mater. If I have the matrix presented in my question I can easily map it with the count of items within a for loop... but I maybe missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution would be to use pandas dataframe which allows you to sort with two columns.

```
widget = {
"name": "item_name",
"xPos": "0",
"yPos": "1"
}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(widget.keys()))
df = df.append(widget, ignore_index=True)
widget = {
"name": "item_name",
"xPos": "1",
"yPos": "1"
}
df = df.append(widget, ignore_index=True)
df.sort_values(by=['xPos', 'yPos'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
name xPos yPos
0  item_name    0    1
1  item_name    1    1
```

Pandas takes care of indexing after sorting. You can put the widget objects in a loop, if that is your specific context of use.